# Web crawler SQLite3 SELECT for next link to crawl is crazy slow

Tags: python, mysql, performance, sqlite, web-crawler

I am making a web crawler in python and have a problem with an sqlite query. The query works but is crazy slow, is there a better way to do this? Normally im pretty good with sql but i really come up against my limits with all these parameters.

Table links contains links that are crawled from websites (href="LINK").
The following sql outputs a link that should be crawled next.

Only x amount of sites should be crawled on a host, in a specific time.

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM links AS b WHERE b.hostname = a.hostname and b.lastCrawledTimestamp < ?)
AS hostLimitCount
FROM links AS a WHERE hostLimitCount < ? and lastCrawledTimestamp < ?
LIMIT 1
```

lastCrawledTimestamp has an INDEX
hostname has an INDEX

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you add the "mysql" tag? You can ask Sqlite for the [query plan](https://sqlite.org/eqp.html) and show it properly formatted in the question. It may reveal more information.

Comment: It uses almost the same syntax. If there is someone who only speaks "MySQL syntax", he also can help me, without even knowing anything about SQLite. The question is not really about SQLite, more about SQL for itself. Also, if someone else has this problem with MySQL, than he probably could use the same solution. In fact, the SQL above, could be used for MySQL AND SQLite.

Comment: SQLs vary widely.  That _looks_ like MySQL code.  MySQL can handle composite indexes; can Sqlite?

Comment: Yes I know.. But you know what I mean.. Obviously you know more about this, than I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery would benefit from

```
INDEX(hostname, lastCrawledTimestame)
```

Also, turning it inside out, like the following, may help:

```
SELECT  a.*, x.hostLimitCount
    FROM  
        (
        SELECT  b.hostname, COUNT(*) AS hostLimitCount
            FROM  links AS b
            WHERE  b.lastCrawledTimestamp < ?
            GROUP BY hostname
            HAVING  hostLimitCount < ?
            LIMIT  1 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  links AS a USING(hostname)
```

which might benefit from that same index.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I should learn more about Joins and these things... Your Query is like a million times faster.

Comment: @Pitchbloas - The principle _in this case_ was to do a "derived table" that whittled down the number of rows efficiently, _then_ reach for the other columns.  And the index is "covering".